# seting a cookie when closing bootstrap allert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I store a cookie when user closes this alert from bootstrap

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

I know how to do it with "onclick" , but is there another way without modifying the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the [alert events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#events) to trigger your code

| Event | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `close.bs.alert` | This event fires immediately when the `close` instance method is called. |
| `closed.bs.alert` | This event is fired when the alert has been closed (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). |

```js
$(".alert").on("closed.bs.alert", (e) => {
  console.log("here's where I would set a cookie")
  
  // doesn't work in StackSnippet sandbox
  // document.cookie = "favorite_framework=Bootstrap; SameSite=None; Secure";
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you,I am still digesting it,  I need to understand this shothand ajax better.

Answer (score 1):

so are you asking how to attach listeners to dom elements without modifying the elements?

```
<script>
    $('.alert-dismissible button.btn-close').click(() => {
        // cookie stuff here.
    });
</script>
```

You can target them, the above is using jquery.

Comment: thank you it helps to understand

Comment: one more question you refere to the div and then you refer to the button. is this to better define the button you want to listen?

Comment: @MaxMuster This is to target the button that has a class of btn-close but only if its a relative of the class alert-dismissible.